# Improving for Loop Performance (Convert to array Operation?)

Tags: performance, matlab

I'm having problems with a rather complicated for Loop Operation.

I have a huge List of entries with multiple entries for one vehicle and need to build a "map" that tells me which entry is for which vehicle.

So i built a for-loop doing this:

```
vehicle_list = unique(Data(1:max,vehicle_column));

for i_vehicle = 1:length(vehicle_list)
  % Retrieve the actual vehicle from the list    
  vehicle = vehicle_list{i_vehicle};
  % Find all elements with the actual vehicle
  flag_vehicle = strncmp( vehicle, ...
   Data(1:end,vehicle_column), length(vehicle));

   % Set all elements with the current index (corresponding to the current
   % vehicle in the list)
   vehicle.map(flag_vehicle) = i_vehicle;
end;
```

As you could imagine, this is taking ages. I tried solutions with ismember and cellfun but that only made it worse.

I know that array functions are a lot faster than for loops but im having trouble finding a way to convert this functions into an array operation.

Anybody got an idea to improve performance?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us what "max" is, and what "actual_vehicle" is.

Comment: My Mistake, I edited it accordingly, "max" was just the end of the matrix.